# Simulink: How to display scope legend through subsystems?

Tags: matlab, scope, legend, simulink

I have a subsystem that displays simulation data collects data from other blocks through Goto/From tag combinations and displays it through a scope. Since this block is part of a Simulink *library* (and not just a model),I cannot integrate a scope *within* it (it will appear as a 'locked scope').

Therefore, I do what Mathworks recommends, which is to offer OutPorts of signals (as in picture), and the user can connect the scopes he wants. The problem is, by doing this, the scope does not display correctly named Legends. Instead of 'Compressor Mass Flow Rate', I get 'Output Data/2: 1'.

What can I do to get a proper display?

PS: I must collect data centrally since the end user wants it that way.[image] [image] [image]

Comment: I think the only option is for the end-user to manually re-label the signals coming out of the library block.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. One of the reasons for using Simulink over Modelica for us has been that everything looks cleaner. The whole point is that we can just hand over something to the end user and he can play with it. Pity that looks less likely now.

Comment: If the library outputs are specified to be non-virtual busses (with associated Simulink.Bus objects defined in the Base Workspace) then the signal names will be inherited (as they are specified in the bus).  However I don't think non-virtual busses can be input directly into a Scope.

Comment: I would suggest this as enhancement request to MathWorks, it certainly makes a lot of sense to me. http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/ then "My Service Requests", and "Create a new service request".

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for your comment, but I don't quite follow. When you say 'specify outputs as non-virtual busses', does that mean that the blocks where the output signal originates should be using a bus? And how would that signal then have it's Simulink.Bus object in the workspace? Having never used busses, I'm unclear about how they work.

Comment: Replace the mux with a Bus Creator.  Then create a [Simulink.Bus](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulink.bus.html) object (with appropriately named signals) in the Base Workspace.  And then within the Bus Creator, set the data-type of the block's output to be the bus in the Base Workspace, and for it to be non-virtual.  You might also need to do the same with the data-type of the Outport block.  Note that your end user will need the Bus object in their base workspace to run the model, so you will need to so something like set the InitFcn callback for the block to create it.

Comment: @Phil Goddard, Hi Phil, you were right, non virtual busses are not accepted as inputs into the scope. I am able to display signals by doing a very complicated Bus Creator >>  Bus Selector >> Mux >> Scope configuration, but a) That still requires the Bus Selector and Mux to be outside the subsystem, and b) Scope only accepts Mux signal. Here's what I did: http://imgur.com/5nvN3p8. Is there any other way?

Comment: I think what you've done is the only available approach.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot for your help. At least it cleared up a part of Simulink that I was really hazy about. What I've done is created a subsystem in my library that internally does the thing I've done here, and double clicking on it opens up the scope inside. It acts like a proxy scope, which the user will have to use instead of the default scope, but at least he gets the legends!